# Ошибка после обновления Opencart c 2.2 До 2.3

Tags: php, opencart

Возникла ошибка после обновления Opencart c 2.2 До 2.3

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on null in /var/www/sozonen/data/www/sabo-shop.com.ua/catalog/view/theme/goshop/template/common/footer.tpl on line 2
```

С чем может быть связано?

вот код

```
<?php 
if($registry->has('theme_options') == true) { 
    $theme_options = $registry->get('theme_options');
    $config = $registry->get('config');

    require_once( DIR_TEMPLATE.$config->get($config->get('config_theme') . '_directory')."/lib/module.php" );
    $modules = new Modules($registry);

    $customfooter_top = $modules->getModules('customfooter_top');
    $customfooter_bottom = $modules->getModules('customfooter_bottom');
    $customfooter_center = $modules->getModules('customfooter');
    $footer_center = $modules->getModules('footer');
```

Comment: Покажите первые N строк этого файла в своем вопросе.

Comment: Покажите первые N строк этого файла /var/www/sozonen/data/www/sabo-shop.com.ua/catalog/view/theme/goshop/template/common/footer.tpl